# Show scoll image when div height is bigger then 1051px

Tags: jquery, image, html, height

I have a div with dynamic content. Some page has more content than the other...

I want to make a function that when my window (div) has a scrollbar (so more content) you get an image right in the screen that shows an arrow... So that the user is aware that he can scroll...

I allready got this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){alert($('#scroller').height());})


if ( $('#scroller').height() < 1051) {

}
else {
   document.write('<div class="scroll"><p><img src="http://www.website.nl/showroom/pijl.gif" alt=""/></p></div>');
}

</script>
```

With this css:

```
#scroller
{
    height:auto;
}
```

Should be working but it doesnt work... The alert does show the height of the div but when de div height is over 1051px it doesnt do anything...

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot document.write after the page has been rendered. You will need to use jquery's dom manipulation methods to create an element.

Replace your document.write with:

`$('body').append('<div class="scroll"><p><img src="http://www.website.nl/showroom/pijl.gif" alt=""/></p></div>');`

Comment: Thanks for the qiuck answer... I tried this: if ( $('#scroller').height() < 100) {
$('body').append('<div class="scroll"><p><img src="http://www.website.nl/showroom/pijl.gif" alt=""/></p></div>');
}
else {

}

But my image is still not showing... When I change the > to < it is showing... What going wrong

EDIT: The div alert in the example is over the 900 so it should display the image...